# Processing.org : Failed to play mp3 files

Tags: audio, processing, mp3

I wrote a game by Processing and I need to play some mp3 files in this game. However, my desktop computer failed to play this sound files due to this error :

p.s. I tested the code in other notebook / desktop computer and it is OK to play the sound. What should I do ? Thanks!

---

12月 11, 2019 9:54:15 上午 com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice 
資訊: JSyn: default output latency set to 80 msec for Windows 10
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.RuntimeException: AudioInput stop attempted when no line created.
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.stop(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)

---

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code? Also, try to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which has this problem.

Comment: And can you please use proper [markup](/editing-help) in your question?